# Generating a hierarchical dependency tree of p2 repository dependencies in Tycho

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, tycho, p2

I'm trying to resolve a version conflict within tycho, where multiple versions of a plugin are loaded at compile time, which is not allowed by the project structure and throws an error during the build.
I've checked the versions I have set in my Manifests to be the same everywhere, but there are too many transitive dependencies to check them all manually. I've tried generating a dependency tree with `mvn dependency:tree` which also shows transitive dependencies from p2 repositories.
Unfortunately it does not show the hierarchical structure of those transitive dependencies, which makes it considerably harder to find the specific required bundle that causes the version conflict.
This small part of the tree shows the problem.

```
[INFO] Building State Chart Feature 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT                      [89/90]
[INFO] --------------------------[ eclipse-feature ]---------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ at.jku.mevss.statechart.feature ---
[INFO] at.jku.mevss:at.jku.mevss.statechart.feature:eclipse-feature:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:cdsl.language:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.oxo42:stateless4j:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.mapdb:mapdb:jar:2.0-beta13:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.0-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] +- net.sdruskat:net.sdruskat.fragment.sun.misc:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.19:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.23:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20200518:compile
[INFO] +- com.helger:jcodemodel:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:at.jku.ase.logging:eclipse-plugin:2.16.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.runtime:jar:3.15.0.v20180817-1401:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.log4j:jar:1.2.15.v201012070815:system
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:at.jku.ase.ulm:eclipse-plugin:2.16.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.core:eclipse-plugin:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] |  \- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.commons.logging:jar:1.2.0.v20180409-1502:system
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:at.jku.mevss.lib:eclipse-plugin:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:at.jku.mevss.util:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:at.jku.mevss.settingsPlugin:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.commons.lang:jar:2.6.0.v201404270220:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:javax.xml.bind:jar:2.2.0.v201105210648:system
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:at.jku.mevss.eventdistributor.service.core:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui:jar:3.110.0.v20180828-1350:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.commons.io:jar:2.2.0.v201405211200:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.commons.collections:jar:3.2.2.v201511171945:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:com.google.guava:jar:28.0.0.jre:system
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:at.jku.mevss.memodel:eclipse-plugin:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.resources:jar:3.13.100.v20180828-0158:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:com.thoughtworks.xstream:jar:1.3.1.v201111240924:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.json:jar:1.0.0.v201011060100:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:com.google.gson:jar:2.8.2.v20180104-1110:system
[INFO] +- at.jku.mevss:at.jku.mevss.statechart.core:eclipse-plugin:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:com.github.oxo42.stateless4j:jar:2.5.0:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.slf4j.api:jar:1.7.10.v20170428-1633:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:javax.xml:jar:1.3.4.v201005080400:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:com.google.guava.failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:javax.xml.stream:jar:1.0.1.v201004272200:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.4_v201201052148:system
...
```

All dependencies that are fetched from p2 repositories don't show there origin, and are therefore hard to debug when causing a version conflict.
Is there a way to generate a tree that also shows the hierarchical structure of dependencies from p2 repository?

Comment: The `dependency:tree` is related to Maven dependencies which rely on the `pom.xml` and not as OSGi on manifest. This is not possible with maven. You could try to use Eclipse cause it has a dependency tree in there if I correctly remember?...

Comment: @khmarbaise I thought just because I'm using tycho, that there may be a way to show the dependency tree too, since it specifically is a plugin to add functionality for OSGI. I mean it already resolves to transitive dependencies, it just doesn't show them in a way that would be convenient for finding issues.